# О предлоге ЧЕРЕЗ: "через больницу к жизни возвращается", а?

Tags: грамотная-речь, диалектизмы

> Оттого слышим и как там наш Чайка поживает. Плохо, если у него **удачные**
>   дни: тогда в запой уходит, ему тяжело потом. Много дней. **Только если
>   через больницу к жизни возвращается**. Так что лично мы теперь редко
>   ему подаём.

**[ЧЕРЕЗ, *предлог*](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7)**

> ...**4.** Указывает на лицо, средство и т. п., при посредстве которого
>   совершается что-л.

Не нравится мне этот через...

А ***удачные*** в "удачные дни" - кавычить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Только если через больницу к жизни возвращается.* Через больницу - с помощью больницы, т.е. докторов - всё нормально, образно: человек метонимию употребил.

И кавычки, по-моему, не нужны, это же прямое значение. Удачные дни - это не "пьяные дни", а дни, когда ему дают деньги, - тогда он и пьёт. Правильно я поняла смысл? Зачем же кавычить?

Answer (score 1):

Я бы лучше "если" перед "через" убрал.

А после "слышим" запятой не надо?

Comment: ЗПТ ни-ни! Слышимость хорошая, *потому слышим и как* (то-сё).

Comment: И правило есть? ))

Comment: Ну конечно есть! Только автор не вытерпел, говорит, выпустил книжку сырую, уже... А она недоправленная, глазнушки! Плакайу... Но читаю дальше.

Answer (score 0):

Полагаю, предлог **через** действительно может быть использован в данной конструкции, но для меня это тоже звучит не совсем привычно. Но, если было указано  такое значение, то, соответственно, оно имеет место быть.

Да, "удачные дни" следует писать в кавычках, т.к. это не является переносным смыслом конкретно слова "удачные", а относится ко всему сочетанию, обозначая период сильного алкогольного опьянения, вызванного каким-либо эмоциональным перепадом.